# What is the proportion of the strength signals between wired and wireless mouse/keyboard?

Tags: power-supply, signal

I understand that the PSU of a desktop PC is creating noise (ripples and ringing) at frequencies that propagate along the cable of the mouse and the keyboard, and radiate those signals through them. The frequencies may be beyond 100 Mhz.

My question is: what is the proportion between the strength of the wired mouse/keyboard radiated signals (which radiate that > 100 Mhz noise signals) opposed to the strength of the signals that radiate from wireless (WiFi) mouse/keyboard?

Comment: Wireless mice/keyboards do not use "WiFi".

Comment: Ok.i understand that they don't use wifi.My intention was to the 2.4 Ghz frequency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's **orders of magnitude** difference in the signal strength. Although virtually every electronic thing radiates some RF energy, most don't radiate much at all unless they're designed to. There's two reasons for this.

1) Making electronics radiate RF effectively usually requires you to have a resonant setup. There's an entire field of electrical engineering just dealing with antenna design to come up with effective ways to resonate electrical signals to allow them to effectively convert the energy into RF. The wireless mouse/keyboard have an antenna specifically designed to convert electricity into RF.

2) Most electronics that could resonate easily creating unwanted RF are purposely designed or changed to not emit RF easily. The FCC states that electronics must not cause unwanted interference so designers have to ensure they don't do so. One example of engineers lowering the amount of RF noise is with CPU clocking. Instead of clocking at the same frequency constantly creating an RF noise spike, they perform spread spectrum clocking so the noise is distributed over a wider bandwidth and is therefore lower at any given frequency.

Comment: The issue is that i had detected an rf signals(+100Mhz)which was emitting from the wired mouse and wired keyboard.I got an explanation that this emitting RF signals are due to the"noise"that was creating from the PSU that propogates to those accessories.I just would like to know,if the strength of that emitting RF signals from the wired mouse/keyboard are the same as the emitting RF signals from the wireless ones?

Comment: @xchcui If you're detecting an RF signal above 100Mhz, it's unlikely that it's caused by the power supply as most are designed to switch at up to 10 Mhz except in rare instances. RF at frequencies where you're seeing it is more than likely the USB signals themselves or possibly from internal to the cpu itself. And the signal strength as I said of either of these possible noise sources should be orders of magnitude lower than what a wireless mouse/keyboard would produce.